# Install Intel core i7 11700 GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

How do I install the current driver for the integrated GPU on Intel i7 11th gen core and use them in Ubuntu?

- Ubuntu 20.10
- kernel 5.8
- Under settings>about I see Grpahics: llvmpipe

I expect to see something related to the Intel graphics driver there instead.
Also running a game works, but is far slower than I expect. So my best guess is that it is not using the correct drivers at the moment.

I experimentally followed a few articles mentioning switching the driver from nvidea to intel with `prime-select` or changing the grub config without improving the graphics performance. But the articles mentioned older Intel models and Ubuntu version and did not explain the changes enough for me to be able to figure out a similar solution that would work for me.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo lshw -c video` and edit your question to include the output of that command please?